# Webpack issue when update 4.x to 5.x

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-hot-middleware, webpack-hot-client

I have a problem when i updated in my project the webpack package to V5.x.
Here is the error :
webpack-hot-client: `entry` Object values must be an Array or Function. Please check your webpack config.

Here is my package.json :

> ````
>     "*.css",
>     "*.scss",
>     "*.sass"   ],   "main": "index.js",   "scripts": {
>     "analyze": "bnr clean:build && bnr analyze",
>     "build:all": "bnr clean:build && bnr build:client && bnr build:server",
>     "build:client": "bnr clean:build && bnr build:client",
>     "build:server": "bnr clean:build  && bnr build:server",
>     "clean": "bnr clean:build",
>     "dev": "bnr dev",
>     "docker": "yarn docker:build && yarn docker:start && yarn docker:status",
>     "docker:build": "docker-compose build --no-cache",
>     "docker:start": "docker-compose up -d",
>     "docker:status": "docker-compose logs -f -t",
>     "flow": "bnr flow",
>     "flow:stop": "bnr flow:stop",
>     "lint": "npm-run-all lint:js lint:style lint:json",
>     "lint:js": "bnr lint:js",
>     "lint:style": "bnr lint:style",
>     "lint:json": "bnr lint:json",
>     "prod": "bnr build:client && bnr build:server && bnr start",
>     "start": "bnr start",
>     "sitemap": "node sitemap-generator.js"   },   "betterScripts": {
>     "analyze": {
>       "command": "npx webpack -p --progress  --hide-modules --config ./tools/webpack/production.client.babel.js",
>       "env": {
>         "NODE_ENV": "analyze"
>       }
>     },
>     "build:client": {
>       "command": "npx webpack --hide-modules --config ./tools/webpack/production.client.babel.js && npx gulp --gulpfile
> tools/gulpfile.js",
>       "env": {
>         "NODE_ENV": "production"
>       }
>     },
>     "build:server": {
>       "command": "npx babel ./src -d ./dist --copy-files && npx webpack --hide-modules --config
> ./tools/webpack/production.server.babel.js",
>       "env": {
>         "NODE_ENV": "production"
>       }
>     },
>     "clean:build": {
>       "command": "rimraf ./public/assets && rimraf ./public/webpack-assets.json"
>     },
>     "dev": {
>       "command": "nodemon ./index.js",
>       "env": {
>         "NODE_PATH": "./src",
>         "NODE_ENV": "development",
>         "PORT": 3000
>       }
>     },
>     "flow": {
>       "command": "npx flow"
>     },
>     "flow:stop": {
>       "command": "npx flow stop"
>     },
>     "lint:js": {
>       "command": "npx eslint --fix ./src ./tools ./index.js"
>     },
>     "lint:json": {
>       "command": "npx prettier --write src/**/**/*.json"
>     },
>     "lint:style": {
>       "command": "npx stylelint --fix ./src/**/*.css, ./src/**/*.scss"
>     },
>     "start": {
>       "command": "node ./index.js",
>       "env": {
>         "NODE_PATH": "./dist",
>         "NODE_HOST": "0.0.0.0",
>         "NODE_ENV": "production",
>         "PORT": 8080
>       }
>     }   },   "husky": {
>     "hooks": {
>       "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
>     }   },   "lint-staged": {
>     "*.{js,jsx}": "eslint --fix",
>     "*.{json,md}": "prettier --write",
>     "*.{scss,sass}": "stylelint --syntax=scss"   },   "nodemonConfig": {
>     "watch": [
>       "src/server.js",
>       "src/handler.js",
>       "src/utils/renderHtml.js",
>       "src/theme/variables.scss"
>     ]   },   "browserslist": [
>     "> 1%",
>     "last 3 versions"   ],   "eslintIgnore": [
>     "tools/flow",
>     "public/assets"   ],   "dependencies": {
>     "@babel/cli": "^7.14.5",
>     "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.5.2",
>     "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.1",
>     "@hapi/address": "^4.1.0",
>     "@koa/router": "^10.1.1",
>     "@loadable/component": "^5.10.2",
>     "@loadable/server": "^5.10.2",
>     "@tweenjs/tween.js": "^18.3.1",
>     "ansi-regex": "^6.0.1",
>     "axios": "^0.23.0",
>     "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
>     "chalk": "^4.1.2",
>     "classnames": "^2.2.6",
>     "d3-ease": "^3.0.1",
>     "del": "^6.0.0",
>     "esm": "^3.2.25",
>     "glob-parent": "^6.0.2",
>     "gulp": "^4.0.2",
>     "gulp-cache": "^1.1.3",
>     "gulp-imagemin": "^8.0.0",
>     "gulp-postcss": "^9.0.0",
>     "gulp-rename": "^2.0.0",
>     "i18next": "^21.3.2",
>     "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^6.1.2",
>     "i18next-node-fs-backend": "^2.1.3",
>     "i18next-resource-store-loader": "^0.1.2",
>     "i18next-xhr-backend": "^3.1.2",
>     "imagemin-mozjpeg": "^9.0.0",
>     "imagemin-pngquant": "^9.0.2",
>     "koa": "^2.8.1",
>     "koa-bodyparser": "^4.2.1",
>     "koa-compress": "^5.1.0",
>     "koa-favicon": "^2.0.1",
>     "koa-helmet": "^6.1.0",
>     "koa-i18next-detector": "^0.7.2",
>     "koa-i18next-middleware": "^1.1.12",
>     "koa-i18next-middleware-fixed": "^1.1.10-b3",
>     "koa-morgan": "^1.0.1",
>     "koa-mount": "^4.0.0",
>     "koa-router": "^10.1.1",
>     "koa-static": "^5.0.0",
>     "koa-webpack": "^6.0.0",
>     "koa-webpack-server": "^0.2.4",
>     "micro-dash": "^8.1.0",
>     "moment": "^2.24.0",
>     "p-min-delay": "^4.0.1",
>     "pm2": "^5.1.2",
>     "qs": "^6.8.0",
>     "rc-animate": "^3.1.1",
>     "rc-queue-anim": "^2.0.0",
>     "rc-scroll-anim": "^2.6.1",
>     "rc-tween-one": "^2.6.3",
>     "react": "^17.0.2",
>     "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.8",
>     "react-dom": "npm:@hot-loader/react-dom@^16.8.6",
>     "react-global-configuration": "^1.4.1",
>     "react-gtm-module": "^2.0.11",
>     "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
>     "react-i18next": "^11.12.0",
>     "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
>     "react-motion": "^0.5.2",
>     "react-player": "^2.9.0",
>     "react-pose": "^4.0.8",
>     "react-router": "^5.0.1",
>     "react-router-config": "^5.0.1",
>     "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
>     "react-router-last-location": "^2.0.1",
>     "react-router-sitemap": "^1.2.0",
>     "react-spring": "^9.3.0",
>     "react-tilt": "^0.1.4",
>     "react-typist": "^2.0.5",
>     "react-youtube": "^7.9.0",
>     "sass-resources-loader": "^2.0.1",
>     "serialize-javascript": "^6.0.0",
>     "styled-components": "^5.3.1",
>     "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.2.4"   },   "devDependencies": {
>     "@babel/core": "^7.6.0",
>     "@babel/node": "^7.14.5",
>     "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.5.5",
>     "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from": "^7.5.2",
>     "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.6.0",
>     "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.2.0",
>     "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.5",
>     "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.0.0",
>     "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
>     "@babel/register": "^7.6.0",
>     "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.0",
>     "@loadable/babel-plugin": "^5.10.0",
>     "@loadable/webpack-plugin": "^5.7.1",
>     "asset-require-hook": "^1.2.0",
>     "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
>     "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
>     "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "^2.3.0",
>     "babel-plugin-istanbul": "^6.1.1",
>     "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "^0.4.24",
>     "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.4",
>     "better-npm-run": "^0.1.1",
>     "compression-webpack-plugin": "^9.0.0",
>     "core-js": "3",
>     "css-loader": "^6.4.0",
>     "css-modules-require-hook": "^4.2.3",
>     "cssnano": "^5.0.8",
>     "eslint": "^8.0.1",
>     "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.0.1",
>     "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
>     "eslint-import-resolver-webpack": "^0.13.1",
>     "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^6.1.1",
>     "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.18.2",
>     "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
>     "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
>     "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.14.3",
>     "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
>     "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
>     "flow-bin": "^0.162.0",
>     "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.7.0",
>     "html-minifier": "^4.0.0",
>     "husky": "^7.0.2",
>     "imagemin-webpack-plugin": "^2.4.2",
>     "lint-staged": "^11.2.3",
>     "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.4.2",
>     "nodemon": "^2.0.13",
>     "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
>     "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
>     "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^6.0.1",
>     "postcss": "^8.3.9",
>     "postcss-loader": "^6.2.0",
>     "postcss-preset-env": "^6.7.0",
>     "prettier": "^2.4.1",
>     "react-dev-utils": "^11.0.4",
>     "react-hot-loader": "^4.12.13",
>     "react-router-sitemap-generator": "^0.0.8",
>     "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.2",
>     "rimraf": "^3.0.0",
>     "sass": "^1.43.2",
>     "sass-loader": "^12.2.0",
>     "static-site-generator-webpack-plugin": "^3.4.2",
>     "stylelint": "^13.13.1",
>     "stylelint-config-prettier": "^9.0.3",
>     "stylelint-config-recommended-scss": "^4.3.0",
>     "stylelint-config-standard": "^22.0.0",
>     "stylelint-scss": "^3.10.1",
>     "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
>     "webpack": "^5.58.2",
>     "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.5.0",
>     "webpack-cli": "4.9.1",
>     "webpack-dev-middleware": "^5.2.1",
>     "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.25.0",
>     "webpack-manifest-plugin": "^4.0.2",
>     "webpack-merge": "^5.8.0",
>     "webpack-node-externals": "^3.0.0"   },   "engines": {
>     "node": ">=8",
>     "npm": ">=5"   } }```
> ````

Here is my base.config.js of webpack :

```
import webpack from 'webpack'
import { WebpackManifestPlugin } from 'webpack-manifest-plugin'
import MiniCssExtractPlugin from 'mini-css-extract-plugin'
import FriendlyErrorsWebpackPlugin from 'friendly-errors-webpack-plugin'
import LoadablePlugin from '@loadable/webpack-plugin'
import config from './config'

const nodeEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'
const isDev = nodeEnv === 'development'

const getPlugins = () => {
  const plugins = [
    new WebpackManifestPlugin({
      fileName: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'public/webpack-assets.json'),
      filter: file => file.isInitial
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: `${config.cssFileName}.css`,
      chunkFilename: `${config.cssChunkFileName}.css`,
      ignoreOrder: true
    }),
    // Setup environment variables for client
    new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({ NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(nodeEnv) }),
    // Setup global variables for client
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      __CLIENT__: true,
      __SERVER__: false,
      __DEV__: isDev
    }),
    new LoadablePlugin({ filename: '../loadable-stats.json', writeToDisk: true })
  ]

  if (isDev) {
    plugins.push(new FriendlyErrorsWebpackPlugin())
  }
  return plugins
}

// Webpack configuration
module.exports = {
  mode: isDev ? 'development' : 'production',
  devtool: isDev ? 'eval-source-map' : 'hidden-source-map',
  context: path.resolve(process.cwd()),
  entry: ['webpack-hot-middleware/client','./src/index.js'],
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'async'
    }
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'public/assets'),
    publicPath: '/assets/',
    filename: `${config.fileName}.js`,
    chunkFilename: `${config.chunkFileName}.js`,
    pathinfo: isDev
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel',
        options: { cacheDirectory: isDev }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          {
            loader: 'css',
            options: {
              importLoaders: 1,
              modules: false,
              sourceMap: true
            }
          },
          { loader: 'postcss', options: { sourceMap: true } }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(scss|sass)$/,
        exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'src/theme/'),
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: {
              hmr: isDev,
              reloadAll: true
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'css',
            options: {
              importLoaders: 2,
              modules: {
                localIdentName: config.cssModulesIdentifier,
                context: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'src')
              },
              sourceMap: true
            }
          },
          { loader: 'postcss', options: { sourceMap: true } },
          {
            loader: 'sass',
            options: {
              sassOptions: {
                outputStyle: 'expanded'
              },
              sourceMap: true
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-resources',
            options: {
              resources: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'src/theme/_include.scss')
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(scss|sass)$/,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'src/theme/'),
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: {
              hmr: isDev,
              reloadAll: true
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'css',
            options: {
              importLoaders: 2,
              modules: false,
              sourceMap: true
            }
          },
          { loader: 'postcss', options: { sourceMap: true } },
          {
            loader: 'sass',
            options: {
              sassOptions: {
                outputStyle: 'expanded'
              },
              sourceMap: true
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'src/locales'),
        loader: 'i18next-resource-store-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|ttf|eot|svg|otf)$/,
        loader: 'url',
        options: { limit: 10240, name: config.staticFilesName }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|webp)$/,
        // Any image below or equal to 10Kb will be converted to base64
        loader: 'url',
        options: { limit: 10240, name: config.staticFilesName }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(mp3|mp4|ogv)$/,
        loader: 'file',
        options: { name: config.staticFilesName }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: getPlugins(),
  resolveLoader: {
    mainFields: ['loader']
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: ['src', 'node_modules'],
    descriptionFiles: ['package.json'],
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
    fallback:{
      fs: false,
      vm: false,
      net: false,
      tls: false
    }
  },
  cache: isDev,
  stats: { children: false }
```

I tried a lot of things and i fixed a lot of issues but for me the entry is an Array, so i don't know why i got this error.

Here there is my server.js (he launches all the programs) :

```
import logger from 'koa-morgan'
import Koa from 'koa'
import bodyParser from 'koa-bodyparser'
import compression from 'koa-compress'
import helmet from 'koa-helmet'
import querystring from 'qs'
import Router from '@koa/router'
import favicon from 'koa-favicon'
import axios from 'axios'
import chalk from 'chalk'
import mount from 'koa-mount'
import serve from 'koa-static'
import Backend from 'i18next-node-fs-backend'
import i18n from 'i18next'
import i18nextMiddleware from 'koa-i18next-middleware-fixed'
import LanguageDetector from 'koa-i18next-detector'
import c from './config'

process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = 0
const app = new Koa()
const router = new Router()
const sendMessage = body =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const config = {
      maxRedirects: 0,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      }
    }

    axios
      .post(
        'https://go.pardot.com/l/138941/2019-07-22/2h6dgb',
        querystring.stringify({ ...body, privacy: true }),
        config
      )
      .then(result => {
        resolve(result.status === 200)
      })
      .catch(e => {
        reject(new Error(e))
      })
  })

const lngDetector = new LanguageDetector()

i18n
  .use(Backend)
  .use(lngDetector)
  .init(
    {
      debug: false,
      fallbackLng: 'fr',
      saveMissing: false,
      react: {
        useSuspense: false
      },
      detection: {
        order: ['path', 'navigator']
      },
      interpolation: {
        escapeValue: false,
        formatSeparator: ',',
        format: (value, format) => {
          if (format === 'uppercase') return value.toUpperCase()
          return value
        }
      },
      preload: ['fr'],
      load: 'languageOnly',
      ns: [
        'global',
        'landing_references',
        'landing_expertises',
        'home',
        'references',
        'expertises',
        'contact',
        'about',
        'partners',
        'team'
      ],
      defaultNS: 'global',
      backend: {
        loadPath: `${path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'src')}/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json`
      }
    },
    async () => {
      // Use helmet to secure Express with various HTTP headers
      app.use(helmet())
      app.use(bodyParser())
      // Compress all requests
      app.use(compression())
      // Use for http request debug (show errors only)
      app.use(logger('dev', { skip: ctx => ctx.status < 400 }))
      app.use(favicon(path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'public/favicon.ico')))
      app.use(i18nextMiddleware.getHandler(i18n, { locals: 'lng' }))

      // Docker serve static trough nginx for better performance
      if (!__DOCKER__) {
        console.log(chalk.magenta('==>   Serve statics with koa'))
        app.use(mount('/locales', serve(path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'src/locales'))))
        app.use(serve(path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'public')))
      }
      if (__DEV__) {
        app.use(mount('/images', serve(path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'src/images'))))
        /* Run express as webpack dev server */
        const webpack = require('webpack')
        const webpackConfig = require('../tools/webpack/base.config')
        const compiler = webpack(webpackConfig)
          const koaWebpack = require('koa-webpack')
        new webpack.ProgressPlugin().apply(compiler)

        const options = {
            compiler,
          devMiddleware: {
            publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath,
            headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
            hot: true,
            writeToDisk: false,
            quiet: true, // Turn it on for friendly-errors-webpack-plugin
            noInfo: true,
            stats: 'minimal',
            serverSideRender: true
          }
        }

        const middleware = await koaWebpack(options)
        app.use(middleware)
      }

      router
        .post('/contact', async ctx => {
          try {
            await sendMessage(ctx.request.body)
            ctx.body = {
              message: 'Votre message a bien été envoyé'
            }
            ctx.status = 200
          } catch (e) {
            ctx.body = {
              message: 'Une erreur est survenue'
            }
            ctx.status = 500
          }
        })
        .get('/', async ctx => {
          ctx.status = 302
          return ctx.redirect(`/${ctx.request.language}`)
        })

        .get('*', async (ctx, next) => {
          return require('./render')(ctx, next)
        })

      app.use(router.routes()).use(router.allowedMethods())
      if (c.port) {
        app.listen(c.port, c.host, err => {
          const url = `http://${c.host}:${c.port}`

          if (err) console.error(chalk.red(`\n==> Error happen ${err}`))
          console.info(chalk.green(`\n==>   Listening at ${url}`))
        })
      } else {
        console.error(chalk.red('\n==> Error : No PORT environment variable has been specified'))
      }
    }
  )
```

UPDATE :
I put some console.log in the compiler file :

```
      for (const key of Object.keys(entry)) {
        const value = entry[key];
        console.log(entry)
        console.log(value)
        console.log(Array.isArray(Object.values(value)))
        if (!Array.isArray(value)) {
          throw new TypeError(
            'webpack-hot-client: `entry` Object values must be an Array or Function. Please check your webpack config.'
          );
```

Console.log return this :

```
  main: { import: [ 'webpack-hot-middleware/client', './src/index.js' ] }
}
{ import: [ 'webpack-hot-middleware/client', './src/index.js' ] }
true
```

So i think that there is a problem with the declaration of variable, because we have to do an Object.values() to get the array.
So idk what can i do to resolve the problem, i will not change the dependencies files...
Thx for your time and your response!

Regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [webpack-hot-middleware setup with single entry point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66322997/webpack-hot-middleware-setup-with-single-entry-point)

Comment: nope i already checked this one it doesn't solve, i spent 10 hours on this problem

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the right example to your situation, but they made some internal changes to the webpack structure:

```
entry: {} allows an empty object now (to allow to use plugins to add entries)
```

here's one of the newer examples I found:

```js
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    about: { import: './about.js', filename: 'pages/[name][ext]' },
  },
};
```

Source: [Webpack v5 internal changes: Entry](https://webpack.js.org/blog/2020-10-10-webpack-5-release/#entry-point-descriptor)

Comment: Thanks for your response. But it didn't work too :(. I update my question, take a look if you want ! :).

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. WebPack Hot Client is not update for the last version of webpack (5.x). If you use Webpack Hot Client, you have to use version 4 of Webpack.

Regards